# AWS Amplify: Adding existing resources from other amplify env

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

Me and my partner are working on a web-project using AWS Amplify, where we have two different Amplify environments in which we are working. Is there a way for me to add the resources present in my partners environment to my environment? More specifically I would like to add/access the existing API gateway and Lambda functions my partner created in his environment to mine (have them show up as resources when using 'amplify status' in my environment). Is this possible?

Comment: The documentation here should help you in your setup : https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/quickstart#team-members-working-on-their-own-sandbox-environments-recommended

Answer (score 0):

This file **aws-exports.js** is the same meaning as **.env**

So everyone can have their own setting

Create a copy **aws-exports.js** and name it **aws-exports.mysetting.js**

When others run your project

> cp aws-exports.mysetting.js aws-exports.js